# filter an object with condition using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I am using Underscore.js library in my application. I have an Object

```
{a:"1", b:"2", c: "3", d:"no", e: "no"}
```

I want to condense this object to have only the properties not having "no" attribute which should result in the below object

```
    {a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"}
```

In Uderscore.js, I used the below code

```
_.omit(obj, 'attr');
```

But in the above code, instead of the 'attr', I need to have a function which will output the keys containing `no` values. Is there a better way to do this. Please let me know how to get the keys having 'no' values.

Comment: What is the expected output / result?

Comment: the expected output is ` {a:"1", b:"2", c: "3"}`. The object with no "no" values.

Comment: Then use omit with a predicate function: `_.omit(obj, function(val) { return val === 'no'})`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_.omit` as

```
var obj = {a:"1", b:"2", c: "3", d:"no", e: "no"};
// _.omit returns a copy of the object
obj = _.omit(obj, function(value, key, object) {
  return (value == "no");
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's `_.omit()` also accepts a 'predicate', which is their terminology for a function similar to `_.filter()`'s:

```js
var o = {a:"1", b:"2", c: "3", d:"no", e: "no"}
console.log(_.omit(o, function(v){
  return v === 'no';
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```